# Hashtag URL rewrite / DOM manipulation causing JS misfire

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, url-rewriting

I'm using the ever-popular Fancybox (http://fancybox.net) as a lightbox plugin, but for some reason it's throwing an Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'fancybox' error and failing to execute.

By ripping out my AJAX / jQuery DOM rewrite script I've confirmed that it is the appending of the hash `http://myurl.com/!#/` that is causing the Fancybox script to misfire in it's targeting, giving a null response on the script.

The details of the AJAX content fetching aren't that important, the point is that it is causing some aspect of Fancybox to not execute correctly (a dependency on the root URL in the main of the plugin code). How can I rewrite the plugin to find the correct root URL and ignore the hash rewrite?

Here is a pastebin of the Fancybox code I need to re-write regarding DOM targeting: http://pastebin.com/s9FjCiai

You can see the in-development site live in my development sandbox here: http://dreamstartest.net

The JS resources are definitely being loaded according to Chrome Developer Tools... any other ideas for debugging?

**EDIT** Opened this as an issue on Github, but like I said in the comment below, the developer looks to be swamped and I'm on a deadline, if anyone is able to find offending lines that might cause problems with the URL hash rewrite I would be eternally grateful!

Comment: Have you submitted this as a bug to the developer?

Comment: Good point.  Unfortunately the developer has abandoned this version which was licensed under GPL in favor of a recent v2, which is now under a non-commercial license. I appreciate his position, but the older version has always worked fine for me.  Unfortunately, the Github repo is swamped with issues right now and I'm on a deadline so I doubt I'll get a fast enough response from the developer.

Comment: I'm deciding on a modal for a project. I think I'll rule out fancybox.

Comment: Let me know if you find something that works with the weird AJAX trick I'm doing.  I have a feeling most of them won't meet my requirements but I don't know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the recently released Fancybox v2 addresses this issue. Download it here: https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox